# Google Test coverage for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, googletest

I have Visual Studio 2012 solution that builds into a static library (.lib) (scons build is available partially) and tests for this code that are written using Google Test framework (compiled into .exe with its own main() function).

How can I get test coverage analysis for this solution **from command line** using Visual Studio 2012 built-in tools or any free VS2012-unrelated software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've managed to do this.

First you need to instrument *.exe files that are used to run Google tests (use /Exclude to avoid generating coverage for unwanted namespaces. as my investigation shows, '*' wildcard works in the end of statements only):

```
vsinstr.exe" mygtests.exe" /COVERAGE /Exclude:std::*
```

**Note: You need to use vsinstr for proper architecture. Use full path in case you are not sure what kind of vsinstr is default**

Then you need to start tests execution monitoring (**Check architecture too**):

```
VSPerfcmd.exe" /START:COVERAGE /OUTPUT:tests.coverage /cs /user:Everyone
```

After that run your *.exe file(s) as usual.

In the end of execution use the following to complete collecting of coverage:

```
VSPerfcmd.exe" -SHUTDOWN
```

You can now get coverage results in tests.coverage file.

Comment: It is absolutely amazing how difficult Microsoft has made this process.